# Case insensitive text search inside binary data on macOS

Tags: macos

I am trying to implement the ability to find text in files that cannot be loaded into an NSString.

*This applies to generic binary files but also to valid text files with a non-Unicode encoding for which I cannot predict the encoding, e.g. ISO Latin or MacRoman.*

I want to search for any text that the user can input in an NSTextField, meaning I like to be able to find anything that is valid Unicode text, in any language and script.

The only assumption I make is that the text I want to find is using UTF-8 encoding (i.e. I don't need to deal with UTF-16). If a file is actually MacRoman-encoded and I search for non-ASCII chars (8th bit set), this doesn't need to find a match.

The thing I try to work around here is that NSString can't load some "badly" encoded files and I still like to find anything around the bad chars.

The search should be insensitive to:

- case (top priority)
- diacritics (low priority)
- unicode composition (low priority)

Another goal is to be fast. This is for a file search utility that might look at many 1000s of large files.

Since I cannot load the data into an NSString, I have to use other search APIs.

What options do I have? Are there libraries that can accomplish this, i.e. find text, skipping over bad characters?

(I thought I could use the system-provided `regex` functions for this, but have [run into a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55885490/43615) with that, too, although that's not as severe).

---

Note: I've tried to convert such data into an NSString with

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
```

and with

```
[NSString stringEncodingForData:data encodingOptions:@{
        NSStringEncodingDetectionAllowLossyKey: @YES,
        NSStringEncodingDetectionLossySubstitutionKey: @" ",
        NSStringEncodingDetectionUseOnlySuggestedEncodingsKey: @YES,
        NSStringEncodingDetectionSuggestedEncodingsKey: @[@(NSASCIIStringEncoding)]
    }
    convertedString:&text usedLossyConversion:nil
];
```

While both appear to work at first, this results in an occasional kernel panic or other hard crash once I call `-[NSString localizedStandardContainsString]` and similar search functions. When it doesn't crash, it works quite well, however.

These crashes appear on my 10.13.6, which is enough for me to avoid this technique, even if Apple may have fixed this in 10.14.3.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that is not very elegant and that may be quite inefficient.

I'm trying to use the system-provided regex library. Problem with that is that it does not handle various things correctly that NSString's find operations do well:

- They are not normalization-savvy, i.e. if I search for a precomposed (NFC) character, it won't find the characher if it's occuring in decomposed (NFD) form in the target data.
- Case insensitive search does not work for latin NFC characters (searching for Ü does not find ü) but only for ASCII letters (a-z).

I'd think that, with the use of smart search algorithms like [Aho–Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) a Unicode-savvy search tree could be generated that considers every variation of a non-ASCII character. But that isn't the case.

So, I thought I'd help the regex with all these variations by building a regex search string that contains them all as a groups, separated by `|`.

I could verify that this algorithm works with latin characters but have no idea whether it will also work with other scripts like chinese, where I believe there are also normalization variations.

The code is rather long, so I'll summarize the algorithm here. I've posted the [code here](https://gist.github.com/tempelmann/165be6f21280caafc8dd0b344e413966).

- I convert the search string into NFC form.
- I look at every char in the search string.
- If the char's code is < 128, then keep it that way.
- Char >= 128 are tested for having different upper/lowercase representations. If they do, I create two alternative search strings for each.
- I end up with one or more search strings.
- Now I convert every search string to the NFC and NFD form, thereby adding more variations.
- Finally, I escape every string for use with regex and concatenate them all with "|" as a separator.

For example, the search string `ä` is turned into `\ä|\Ä|\ä|\Ä` with ä and Ä using both NFC and NFD representations. In binary form the string looks like this:

```
5C C3 A4 7C 5C C3 84 7C 5C 61 CC 88 7C 5C 41 CC 88
```