# Seeking Unicode-savvy function for searching text in binary data

Tags: regex, search, boyer-moore

I need to find unicode text inside binary data (files).

I'm seeking **any C or C++ code or library** that I can use on macOS. Since I guess this is also useful to other platforms, so I rather make this question not specific to macOS.

On macOS, the `NSString` functions, meeting my unicode savvyness needs, can't be used because they do not work on binary data.

As an alternative I've tried the POSIX complient `regex` functions provided on macOS, but they have some limitations:

- They are not normalization-savvy, i.e. if I search for a precomposed (NFC) character, it won't find the characher if it's occuring in decomposed (NFD) form in the target data.
- Case insensitive search does not work for latin NFC characters (searching for Ü does not find ü).

Example code showing these results is below.

What code or library is out there that fulfills these needs?

I do not need regex capabilities, but if there's a regex lib that can handle these requirements, I'm fine with that, too.

**Basically, I need unicode text search with these options:**

- **case-insensitive**
- **normalization-insensitive**
- **diacritics-insensitive**
- works on arbitrary binary data, finding matching UTF-8 text fragments

Here's the test code showing the results from using the TRE regex implementation on macOS:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

void findIn (const char *what, const char *data, int whatPre, int dataPre) {
    regex_t re;
    regcomp (&re, what, REG_ICASE | REG_LITERAL);
    int found = regexec(&re, data, 0, NULL, 0) == 0;
    printf ("Found %s (%s) in %s (%s): %s\n", what, whatPre?"pre":"dec", data, dataPre?"pre":"dec", found?"yes":"no");
}

void findInBoth (const char *what, int whatPre) {
    char dataPre[] = { '<', 0xC3, 0xA4, '>', 0};        // precomposed
    char dataDec[] = { '<', 0x61, 0xCC, 0x88, '>', 0};  // decomposed
    findIn (what, dataPre, whatPre, 1);
    findIn (what, dataDec, whatPre, 0);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char a_pre[] = { 0xC3, 0xA4, 0};        // precomposed ä
    char a_dec[] = { 0x61, 0xCC, 0x88, 0};  // decomposed ä
    char A_pre[] = { 0xC3, 0x84, 0};        // precomposed Ä
    char A_dec[] = { 0x41, 0xCC, 0x88, 0};  // decomposed Ä

    findInBoth (a_pre, 1);
    findInBoth (a_dec, 0);
    findInBoth (A_pre, 1);
    findInBoth (A_dec, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
Found ä (pre) in <ä> (pre): yes
Found ä (pre) in <ä> (dec): no
Found ä (dec) in <ä> (pre): no
Found ä (dec) in <ä> (dec): yes
Found Ä (pre) in <ä> (pre): no
Found Ä (pre) in <ä> (dec): no
Found Ä (dec) in <ä> (pre): no
Found Ä (dec) in <ä> (dec): yes
```

Desired output: All cases should give "yes"

Comment: Well, that's sad. I'm trying to write a better grep (one that can handle any unicode representation) and my question is voted down for what - being too impossible to imagine?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by writing my own pre-precessor, generating a regular expression that combines all the alternatices (case and normalization but not diacritics) and passing that to the regex function.

The complete solution is [documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55892528/43615).